# Can I use perfmon to measure my non-local (internet) bandwidth total from my machine?

Tags: windows-8.1, bandwidth, performance-monitor

I am looking for a quick way to measure my laptop's internet usage as a running total (rather than a point-in-time data plot).  Performance monitor seems to offer a lot of options, but I am not sure what to use. I'm not looking to find out my overall LAN use, just the total from my system.  I am hoping to use a built-in tool, if possible.  It's a Win8 system.

Comment: This type of tracking isn't normally done on the client side.  Your better off doing it by client on the network device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Log bandwidth usage locally](http://superuser.com/questions/268133/log-bandwidth-usage-locally)

Comment: Possible duplicate, yes, but I was hoping for an answer regarding perfmon.  I know there are other utilities out there.